# Firestore's FieldValue.increment(1) increments twice

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a webhook in place to read events from AWS SNS and on every event, I'm updating the respective field in firestore.

My intention is to keep incrementing the event count, and to achieve this I'm using `FieldValue.increment(1)`

But it increments twice for some events. I've double-checked the webhook invocation and the code to update the count is called once.

*This is a serverless function hosted in vercel

```
const sentMailAnalytics = async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
    try {

        // ...above this was code to get data from the event

        const updatedRecieverLog: SentNewsletterRecipientsAnalytics = {
            ...receivers,
            status: {
                ...receivers.status,
                [eventType]: true,
            },
        };

        await db
            .doc(`${firestoreCollections.NEWSLETTERLOGRECIEVER}/${receivers.id}`)
            .update({
                ...updatedRecieverLog,
            });

        await db
            .doc(
                `${firestoreCollections.NEWSLETTERLOG}/${receivers.newsletter_log_id}`
            )
            .set(
                {
                    analytics: {
                        [eventType]: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1),
                    },
                },
                {
                    merge: true,
                }
            );
        
        // ... below this was catch block and returning response
};
```

This is happening quite frequently. Any pointer as to why this is happening and how to fix this ?

Comment: Nothing in the code you shared jumps out as causing the `FieldValue.increment(1)` to be called twice. I've also never seen a single call to `FieldValue.increment(1)` incrementing the value twice. So I recommend investigating whether the code you shared is being called multiple times, or if there are other places that might be incrementing the same value.

Comment: Hey, @FrankvanPuffelen thanks for replying. I've checked the code and function logs, its only being called once and there is no other place where this field is being incremented. Also, the `firebase` instance I'm using is imported from the `firebase` module itself, not from `firebase-admin`, and on my client I've enabled persistance I'm not sure but could this be any how connected ?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I found the issue. As you told the function was being invoked by another environment. Due to which there was this double increment.
Thanks for this. 
It was a silly thing 

Comment: Good to hear that you found the problem @Abhishek 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same function was called from another environment due to which the increment was being triggered twice.

Just needed some fresh start of debugging